# Calling an email script from another script using ssmtp on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, email, ssmtp

I have an issue with a script, which works fine except that it only sends email when I run it directly from the shell but when called during crontab it doesn't send the emails.

There are 2 scripts the main script which does a backup and it calls another script which sends the email. the backup script dump the summary of the operation in a file and reads the file again when to pass it to the email sender script to send. Based on how ssmtp works that's the architecture I have come up with.

I needed to change the subject based on the success or failure of the operation. I have been using my gmail thus using the ssmtp library to send the email.

How to make the backup script send the email when called by `crontab` schedule?

```
#!/bin/bash

# File system Parameters
#=========================================================================
TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H.%M.%S`
TODAYS_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

BACKUP_PATH="/mnt/backups/mongo"
SCRIPT_PATH="/root/script"
FILE_NAME="mongodb-$TIMESTAMP"

# Email Parameters
#=========================================================================
TEMPLATE_FILE="/tmp/template.txt"
EMAIL_SUBJECT_CONTEXT="Xylo"
EMAIL_RECIPIENT="myeamil"
EMAIL_SENDER="DB man"
#=========================================================================

BACKUP_PATH=$BACKUP_PATH/$TODAYS_DATE


echo; echo "files will be geneated in  $BACKUP_PATH" | tee $TEMPLATE_FILE
#=========================================================================

[ ! -d  $BACKUP_PATH ] && mkdir -p $BACKUP_PATH || : 

if [ -d "$BACKUP_PATH" ]; then
    cd $BACKUP_PATH

    TMP_BACKUP_DIR="$BACKUP_PATH/mongodb-$TIMESTAMP"

    echo; echo "=> $(date +%F-%H.%M.%S) Backing up Mongo Server: $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT" | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE; echo -n ' ' ;


    if [ "$MONGOUSERNAME" != "" -a "$MONGOPASSWORD" != "" ]; then
        $MONGODUMP_PATH --host $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -u $MONGOUSERNAME -p $MONGOPASSWORD --out $TMP_BACKUP_DIR >> /dev/null
    else 
        $MONGODUMP_PATH --host $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT --out $TMP_BACKUP_DIR >> /dev/null
    fi

    echo; echo "=> $(date +%F-%H.%M.%S) Mongo Server: $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT  backup files generated"  | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE; echo -n ' ';

    if [ -d "$TMP_BACKUP_DIR" ]; then

        if [ "$FILE_NAME" == "" ]; then

            FILE_NAME = "mongodb-$TIMESTAMP"
        fi

        echo; echo "=> $(date +%F-%H.%M.%S) dumping file into  $FILE_NAME.tar.gz"  | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE; echo -n ' ';

        $TAR_BIN_PATH --remove-files -czf $FILE_NAME.tar.gz $TMP_BACKUP_DIR >> /dev/null

        if [ -f "$FILE_NAME.tar.gz" ]; then

            echo "=> $(date +%F-%H.%M.%S) successfully generated file $FILE_NAME.tar.gz of size: `du -sh $FILE_NAME.tar.gz` " | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE; echo;

            echo; echo "=> $(date +%F-%H.%M.%S) Uploading $FILE_NAME.tar.gz to $S3_BUCKET_NAME on s3" | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE; echo -n ' ';

                s3cmd put $FILE_NAME.tar.gz s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$S3_BUCKET_PATH/$FILE_NAME.tar.gz

                filename=s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$S3_BUCKET_PATH/$FILE_NAME.tar.gz
        count=$(s3cmd ls ${filename} | awk "\$4 == \"${filename}\" { print \$4 }" | wc -l)
#            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
         if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then

                echo "!!!!=> File $FILE_NAME.tar.gz could not be added to s3" | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE
                /bin/sh "$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh" "$EMAIL_RECIPIENT" "$EMAIL_SENDER" "$EMAIL_SUBJECT_CONTEXT BACKUP FAILURE [s3 Upload]" "$(cat $TEMPLATE_FILE)"
            else

               echo "=> $(date +%F-%H.%M.%S) File $FILE_NAME.tar.gz has successfully be added to s3" | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE
                           /bin/sh "$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh" "$EMAIL_RECIPIENT" "$EMAIL_SENDER" "$EMAIL_SUBJECT_CONTEXT BACKUP SUCCESSFUL" "$(cat $TEMPLATE_FILE)"

            fi
            if [ -d "$TMP_BACKUP_DIR" ]; then
                    rm -rf "$TMP_BACKUP_DIR"
            fi
         else

            echo "!!!=> Failed to create backup file: $BACKUP_PATH/$FILE_NAME.tar.gz"  | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE; echo;
            /bin/sh "$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh" "$EMAIL_RECIPIENT" "$EMAIL_SENDER" "$EMAIL_SUBJECT_CONTEXT BACKUP FAILURE [Failed to gzip $FILE_NAME.tar.gz]" "$(cat $TEMPLATE_FILE)"
        fi

    else
        echo; echo "!!!=> Failed to backup mongoDB or Nothing to Back up"  | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE; echo; 
        /bin/sh "$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh" "$EMAIL_RECIPIENT"  "$EMAIL_SENDER"  "$EMAIL_SUBJECT_CONTEXT BACKUP FAILURE [Nothing to back up]" " $(cat $TEMPLATE_FILE)"

    fi
 else
     echo "!!!=> Failed to create backup path: $BACKUP_PATH" | tee -a $TEMPLATE_FILE
     /bin/sh "$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh" "$EMAIL_RECIPIENT" "$EMAIL_SENDER" "$EMAIL_SUBJECT_CONTEXT BACKUP FAILURE [Failed to create backup folder]" "$(cat $TEMPLATE_FILE)"
 fi
```

this is the sending  script

```
#!/bin/bash
Now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
SSMTP="$(which ssmtp)"


TEMPLATE="/tmp/s3_backup_mail.txt"

echo "To: $1" > $TEMPLATE
echo "From: $2" >> $TEMPLATE
echo "Subject: $3" >> $TEMPLATE
echo " " >> $TEMPLATE
echo  "$4" >> $TEMPLATE

$SSMTP $1 < $TEMPLATE
#rm $TEMPLATE
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of gotchas when running something from crontab:

- One's path in crontab is more limited than when at a console.  This can be fixed by making sure the scripts have a line like `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` near the beginning of the script
- Scripts with "bashism"s in them have a hard time running from cron.  The easiest way to fix this is to make sure the very first line of the scripts is the line `#!/bin/bash` by itself.  More explanation and discussion of bashisms: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Comment: Hello Thanks or the insight. so basically my fault was not having the `#!/bin/bash` for the email sending script if I understood well.

Comment: Hello I have tried couple of things for example adding `#!/bin/bash` to the email sending script. I have also used the source command to call the email script(either source `"$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh"` or `"./$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh"`) I have used , I have changed the `sh` at the beginning to `/bin/sh "$SCRIPT_PATH/s3_backup_email_sender.sh"` and still no success

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` has to be the very first line.  If you want more help, please edit the question and post the entire scripts here.

Comment: I have pasted it in the main question. thank you and both scripts have `#!/bin/bash`